# Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to integer

Tags: java, autoboxing

The int should autobox but I do not know why it is not. When i try to compile, it gives me an incompatible types error. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int first = console.nextInt();
    while (first!=0) {
        first=console.nextInt();
        list.add(first);
    }
    System.out.println("Your first list: " + list);
}
```

Comment: What is your version set to, need at least 1.5 for autoboxing?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error?

Comment: variable name `first` is pretty unclear and it also should be `String.valueOf(list.get(0))`... besides; calling `first=console.nextInt();` _twice_ will skip half of the values.

Comment: Do you have another class named `Integer`?

Answer (score -1):

You probably imported the library incorrectly. You should have something like that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score -2):

- try to used Java later than 5 or latest version of Java(Currently it is JDK11).
- Make sure that your input is always integer.Otherwise you will face to "InputMismatchException".

  - Your code expected to get an integer, so if you give some string , your code will not work any more
- make sure that , you have imported  from right library.

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  ```
- make sure your language setting level is 5.0 or higher. you should check the setting in your IDE setting.